# Поворот ui за камерой?

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]На сцене присутствует Canvas c Image в нем - Canvas является дочерним для камеры и поворачивается за ним - но проблема в том, что Image не поворачивается за камерой, но ведь является дочерним Canvas - почему?

```
 GameObject ParentTransform = transform.parent.gameObject;
    transform.position = new Vector3(ParentTransform.transform.position.x, ParentTransform.transform.position.y, ParentTransform.transform.position.z);
```

Удивлен почему для оранжевого круга не работает следующий скрипт

Comment: wat? что-то не ясно какого эффекта ты пытаешься достичь. Особенно учитывая тот факт, что UI всегда находится "прилепленным" к экрану  и пользователь видит его как 2D

Comment: ну а мне необходимо что бы ui перемещался за камерой в vr - как указатель

Comment: можешь добавить визуально что у тебя там и чего ты хочешь? пока непонятно причем тут в таком случае вообще ui. При UI камера итак всегда смотрит на canvas и его элементы

Comment: вот этот оранжевый "указатель" - как раз и не перемещается за canvas

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему

```
void RotAin()
{
    int x = 1;
    if (x==1)
    {
gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.rotation.w, transform.rotation.w, gameObject.transform.position.z);
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.rotation.w, gameObject.transform.rotation.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);
    }

}
```

и `void RotAin()` вызываю в Update